# Reading from the web using the readLines() command in R: getting error message saying that the connection cannot be opened

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am enrolled in an online course on R programming. This week I was supposed to learn to read from the web using the readLines() command.

I basically used the same code as in the lecture slides, and you can find the code I used below.

```
connection <- url("https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=HI-I6C0AAAAJ&hl=en")
htmlCode <- readLines(con = connection)
```

Nevertheless, I always ended up getting the error message which basically informed me that the the connection cannot be opened. Below please find the specific error message that was returned.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ6cW.png)

I have tried the getURL() command enabled by the RCurl package and ended up having the same error. I would greately appreciate it if someone could help with this confusing issue. Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: I can't replicate this - I get the expected output. Are you behind a firewall or anything that might be blocking access?

Comment: Please don't include error messages via image. Only use images when an image is necessary.

Comment: And welcome to the stack! Do take the [tour] if you haven't already

Comment: I also can't replicate this. I also get the expected output.